Bootstrap Bundle JS Script Breaks Dropdown Menu in Laravel
I’m relatively new to Laravel, and I'm currently using it on my Ubuntu 2024 system with Apache2.
I recently installed Laravel UI, which came with a nice navigation bar. I made some modifications but left the dropdown menu next to the profile untouched.
Later, I attempted to implement Bootstrap's Toast system using bootstrap.Toast. However, I encountered a console error stating that "bootstrap" is undefined. To resolve this, I included the following bundle script:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

This allowed the Toast system to work, but unfortunately, it caused the dropdown menu to stop functioning. I even tried creating a completely new dropdown from scratch, and it worked perfectly as long as I didn't include the Bootstrap bundle script.
My dropdown menu code:
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

Toast show code:
var toastInstance = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastElement);
toastInstance.show();

Why does adding the Bootstrap bundle script break the dropdown menu? Is there a way to resolve this issue while still using both the Toast and dropdown components?
After some testing, I mistakenly added the script:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

twice, next to each other. This made both the Toast and dropdown menus work.
It’s a solution, but why is this working? What is Laravel doing behind the scenes?
